# Script to convert bit blasted netlist into bus format

Tags: text-processing, compression

I have signals like

```
signal[3]_and_[31]
signal[3]_and_[30]
signal[3]_and_[29]
signal[3]_and_[28]
...
signal[3]_and_[0]

signal[2]_and_[31]
signal[2]_and_[30]
signal[2]_and_[29]
signal[2]_and_[28]
...
signal[2]_and_[0]
..
...
```

and I want it to be converted to

```
signal[3:0]_and_[31:0]
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: Note that converting gate level back to RTL is not a matter of generic text processing that has no understanding of Verilog.  Even simple restoration of buses isn't.  This is not just because the question ignores identifier escaping, either.  (-:

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a one line per bit blasted signal nane we run the following Perl code and turn it into the corresponding bus notation.

```
perl -MList::Util=max,min -lne '
  BEGIN {
   $sig_re = qr/signal\[(\d+)]_and_\[(\d+)]/;
   $bus_fmt = q/signal[%d:%d]_and_[%d:%d]/;
  }

  /^$sig_re$/ and push(@A,$1), push(@B,$2);

  print(sprintf($bus_fmt,
           max(@A), min(@A),
           max(@B), min(@B)))
                 if eof;
' signals.bit_blasted > signals.bussed
```

Comment: not getting the OP's expected output...

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'signal[3]_and_[31]' | awk -F'[][]' '{ print "signal[" $2 ":0]_and_[" $4 ":0]"; }'
signal[3:0]_and_[31:0]
```